# Javascript: Reversing the loop ouput

Tags: javascript

Basically i'm creating a script to display the place value for set of numbers. Here's my script:

```
var arrn = '3252';
var temp = 0;
var q = arrn.length;
var j = 0;

for (var i = q-1; i >= 0; i--,j++) {
    if (j!=0) temp = temp + ' + ';
    {
        temp += arrn[i] * Math.pow(10, j);
    }
}
alert(temp);
```

My goal is to achieve 3000 + 200 + 50 + 2. But i get  2 + 50 + 200 + 3000. I tried temp.reverse() & sort functions but doesn't seem to work. Please help

Comment: Your code is rather mangled. You have a statement after your `if` and then braces. I won't try and fix your code but you should look carefully at that line. Do you do you mean `if (j!=0) {temp=temp +' + '; temp +=arrn[i]*Math.pow(10,j); }`? If not, why are the braces there?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if(j!=0)temp=temp +' + ';
{
    temp +=arrn[i]*Math.pow(10,j);
}
```

to

```
if(j!=0) {
  temp=' + ' + temp;
}
temp = arrn[i]*Math.pow(10,j) + temp;
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/cuneco/3/)

---

Side note: Your braces in the first code block above are *very* misleading. What you have:

```
if(j!=0)temp=temp +' + ';
{
    temp +=arrn[i]*Math.pow(10,j);
}
```

is

```
if(j!=0)temp=temp +' + ';
temp +=arrn[i]*Math.pow(10,j);
```

which is to say

```
if(j!=0) {
    temp=temp +' + ';
}
temp +=arrn[i]*Math.pow(10,j);
```

the block in your version is not associated with the `if`, it's just a freestanding block.

---

Side note #2: Since you're using `temp` as a string everywhere else, I would initialize it with `''` rather than with `0`. [Example](http://jsbin.com/cuneco/2) The reason your string didn't end up with an extraneous `0` was really *quite* obscure. :-)

Comment: @user2672112: Hit refresh, I realized a second or so after posting that you were adding to `temp` again elsewhere. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the number to the beginning of the string instead of at the end:

```
for (var i = q - 1; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
  if (j != 0) {
    temp = ' + ' + temp;
  }
  temp = arrn[i] * Math.pow(10, j) + temp;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/rh9oso3f/

Side note: You are using some confusing brackets in your code after the `if` statement. As there is a statement following the `if` statement, the brackets starting on the next line becomes just a code block, but it's easy to think that it's supposed to be the code that is executed when the condition in the `if` statement is true.

Another side note: the `language` attribute for the `script` tag was deprecated many years ago. Use `type="text/javascript"` if you want to specify the language.

Answer (score 0):

How about `temp.split("+").reverse().join(" + ")`?

Comment: It gives me this folkol, 2502003000

Comment: @user2672112: folkol's current answer works: http://jsbin.com/cuneco/5 (I wouldn't do it this way, I'd build the string in the correct order on purpose, but it *does* work other than messing up your spaces). I don't know if you were perhaps looking at an earlier copy and he/she slipped in a ninja edit...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way. I know it can be optimised. But it works

```
var arrn='3252';
var temp=0;

var q=arrn.length;
var res = [];
var j=0;
for(var i=q-1;i>=0;i--,j++)
{
    temp += parseFloat(arrn[i])*Math.pow(10,j);
    res.push(arrn[i]*Math.pow(10,j));
}
res.reverse();
alert(res.join('+') + " = " + temp);
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/he7p8y5m/

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrn='3252';
var temp=new Array();

var q=arrn.length;
for(var i=0;i<=q-1; i++){
    temp.push(arrn[i]*Math.pow(10,(q-i-1)));
}
temp = temp.join('+');
alert(temp);
```